# Module dependecies and manifest file not merge with my application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-library, android-module

I have created my android project as a module following this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Then Added this module in new demo android project as a .aar library

But when I am running my demo application it is giving me error Gradle dependencies not found and Module activities as well.

I have to add manually all Gradle dependencies that I used in module while developing. Also, need to declare all activities in demo application manifest.

Is there any other way that I can merge all module Gradle dependencies and module manifest with my demo application?